# How can I fire function or what event after data is bounded to the component?

Tags: angular, typescript, web, angular-material

I use angular material select in my angular 10 project.

Here is template:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="defaultSelection" (selectionChange)="onSelect($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let name of enumKeys" [value]="name">
        {{enum[name]}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Here is component:

```
export class EnumSelectionComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() enum: Object = Status;
  defaultSelection = Status.Info;
  enumKeys=[];

  constructor() { 
    this.enumKeys=Object.keys(this.enum);  
  }

  onSelect(selection) { 
    alert(selection)
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  
}
```

After the selection options are generated in *ngFor directive I need to fire a function.

Those my question is how do I know that options are generated in *ngFor directive do I have any indication for it so that I can run some event handler?

Comment: I am not getting ur point but one thing wrong I have noticed is @Input() variable values can be accessible in ngOnInit(). You are trying to get value of Input() into the constructor. So I fill enum value is blank when you are assigning into contractor. put it on ngOnInit()

Comment: @DevangPatel just needs to fire function after select contains data that displays.